# How do I proceed with the following coulomb integral?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen, quantum-chemistry

I am trying to solve the $H_{2}^{+}$ ion problem using Fourier transform approach.

The Hamiltonian that I am trying to solve is as follows, $$H=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m_{e}}\nabla^{2}_{e}-\frac{e^{2}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|\vec{r}-\vec{R}|}-\frac{e^{2}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|\vec{r}|}+\frac{e^{2}}{R}$$ I have put one of the nucleus at the origin. To solve   this I have used the following trial wave functions for the ground state $$\psi=c_{1}\psi_{s}(\vec{r})+c_{1}\psi_{s}(\vec{r}-\vec{R})$$ Here S represents the s orbital. I have excluded spin parts and make the nucleus stationary. To solve this I evaluated the  following integral.$$J=\int d^{3}\vec{r}\frac{1}{\pi a_{0}^{3}}\exp(-{2r/a_{0}})\bigg(\frac{e^{2}}{R}-\frac{e^{2}}{r'}\bigg)$$
where, $r'=|\vec{r}-\vec{R}|$ and Here, R is the distance of the second nucleus from the origin and first nucleus is already placed at the origin.

I used Fourier transform to solve this integral, 
$$\frac{1}{\pi a_{0}^{3}}\exp(-{2r/a_{0}})=\frac{a^{4}}{8\pi^{3}}\int \frac{\exp(i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r})}{(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}}d^{2}\vec{k}$$ and $\frac{2}{a_{0}}=a$ and $\vec{r'}=\vec{r}-\vec{R}$ The other Fourier transform that is required is to solve this integral is ,$$\frac{1}{r'}=\frac{1}{2 \pi^{2}}\int\frac{\exp(i\vec{k'}\cdot \vec{r'})}{k'^{2}}d^{3}\vec{k'}$$ I really don't know how to get the following step,

$$J=\frac{e^{2}}{2 \pi^{2}}\int d^{3}\vec{k} \exp(i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R})\Bigg(\frac{1}{(k^{2}+a^{2})}+\frac{a^{2}}{(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}}\Bigg)$$ Now reverting back to the space coordinates we get the following answer $$J=\frac{e^{2}}{R}\exp(-2R/a_{0})\bigg(1+\frac{R}{a_{0}}\bigg)$$

Can someone explain how to get that intermediate step just before the final answer using the Fourier transform. I struggled a lot but I didn't get the answer. I followed the book "/Quantum  Mechanics B.K Agarwal & Hari Prakash PHI publication" chapter 17. Molecules , page number 366